# shutting down Excel application when Closing wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, user-controls, vsto

I have got an excel application running which on parsing the excel sheet displays a wpf window (from other project however in same workspace).

```
[STAThread]
        public void Run()
        {
            TableStructure = null;

            parser = new ExcelParser.WorksheetParser(TableStructure);

            GeneralTree<string> rawRBS = parser.GetRawTree();

            MainWindow main = new MainWindow(rawRBS, parser.WorkSheet);
            main.ShowDialog();
        }
```

The problem here is when i close the mainwindow.. closing mainwindow shuts the whole application down along with excel workbook too. I want excel workbook opened even when main window is closed.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: how do you open excel workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `main.ShowDialog()` with:

```
var app = new Application();
app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
app.Run(main);
```

You should note that unless you've setup a tray icon or some other kind of UI, you'll have no way of shutting down the app (short of killing the process).

Comment: Thanks. but still the same behavior. even worst because it does not kill the EXCEL process running. closing the window now, leaves the excel app running in background.

Comment: By saying active,I meant that user should still be seeing workbook opened. not closing it.... in case there are changes.. i can save them manually.